# I want to display the product options value in Magento Product Page

Tags: magento

I want to display the product options value in a Magento Product Page. I tried this code:

```
<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('color'); ?>
```

but the options are not showing up.

Comment: A bit more context (where are you using this snippet, possible error messages) would help us to help you ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on the actual product view paghe you can use a helper to get what you want:

```
echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getColor(), 'color');
```

or

```
echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getData('attribute_code'), 'attribute_code');
```

Alternatively you can try this:

```
$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('color')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can this one,

```
<?php $attributeValue = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getColor();?>
```